# How do i implement cookielib to create a session

Tags: python

```
import urllib2
import urllib

url = "http://www.torn.com/authenticate.php"
username = raw_input("Your username; ")
password = raw_input("Your password: ")
query = {'player':username, 'password':password}
data_query = urllib.urlencode(query)
sending_data = urllib2.Request(url, data_query)
print sending_data()
response = urllib2.urlopen(sending_data)
print "You are currently logged unto to:", response.geturl()
print response.read()
```

How do i implement the cookielib to create a session and please explain line by line Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from cookielib import CookieJar

cj = CookieJar()
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'j_username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.open("http://www.torn.com/authenticate.php", login_data)
```

First, you want to initialize your CookieJar. Then you encode your credentials, as they need to be sent in a certain form to be read by the PHP server. Then you have to initialize an opener, which is basically an HTTP client, and configure it to use your CookieJar. Then submit your login info to the server to create the session and generate cookies. To continue using these cookies, use `opener.open()` instead of `urllib2.urlopen` (although you can still use `urllib2.Request()` to generate the requests.

Comment: Beat me by 21 seconds.

Comment: @8BitAce Please am a beginnner, I don't still understand your explanatio, If you don't mind breaking it down bit by bit

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an `OpenerDirector` for that.
From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#examples):

```
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

So in order to also pass data your code should look something like this:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import cookielib

url = "http://www.torn.com/authenticate.php"
username = raw_input("Your username; ")
password = raw_input("Your password: ")
query = {'player':username, 'password':password}
data_query = urllib.urlencode(query)
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
response = opener.open(url, data_query)
print "You are currently logged unto to:", response.geturl()
print response.read()
```

Comment: Thank you but can you please explain line 9 and 10.

Comment: @SubomiOluwalana `cj = cookielib.CookieJar()` basically creates a new CookieJar and assigns it to the variable `cj`. Then you create an opener (which works almost exactly like `urllib2.urlopen()` and tell it to use your created `CookieJar` to store cookies in.